# PHP Array compare using loops

Tags: php

I am using this piece of code to compare two php arrays, I got all matched items rightly but unfortunately i am not succeeding in getting non matched items. Here is my code.

```
<?php 

$filter1 = "blueberries,abc,cornstarch,sugar";
$cval = strtoupper($filter1);         
$parts1 = explode(',',$cval);

$filter2 = "water,blueberries,sugar,cornstarch";
$values = strtoupper($filter2);
$parts2 = explode(',', $values);


$m=0;
$nm=0;


for($i = 0; $i< count($parts1); $i++)
{

for($j = 0; $j< count($parts2); $j++)
{

if($parts1[$i] == $parts2[$j])
{
$m++;
$p[] = $parts1[$i];
}
else{
$nm++;
$q[] = $parts1[$i];
}

}

}

echo $m;
echo "<br />";
echo $nm;
echo "<br />";
print_r($p);
echo "<br />";
print_r($q);

?>
```

Can someone help me sorting out this problem, As i **dont want to use builtin array comparison functions.**

Comment: use `array_interesect` and `array_diff`

Comment: Sorry i want to use loops thanks.

Comment: Which raises the question, why do you want to use loops rather than the built-in functions?

Comment: This is absolutely ridiculous, once you compare the arrays you will need to do the for loops all over again to compare the other array. Stop fighting the inbuilt functions

Answer (score 2):

I would use the internal functions for this (if I understood your question)

Matched:

```
$matched = array_intersect($parts1, $parts2);
```

Difference:

```
$difference = array_diff($parts1, $parts2);
```

Or in your world of for loops:

```
<?php
    $filter1 = "blueberries,abc,cornstarch,sugar";
    $cval = strtoupper($filter1);
    $parts1 = explode(',', $cval);

    $filter2 = "water,blueberries,sugar,cornstarch";
    $values = strtoupper($filter2);
    $parts2 = explode(',', $values);

    $matched = $not_matched = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($parts1); $i++)
    {

        if (in_array($parts1[$i], $parts2))
        {
            $matched[] = $parts1[$i];
        }
        else
        {
            $not_matched[] = $parts1[$i];
        }

    }

    print_r($matched);
    print_r($not_matched);
?>
```

I have been working on adding another loop instead of using in_array() but I'm not going to update my answer for two reasons.

1) Use

```
$matched = array_intersect($parts1, $parts2);
$difference = array_diff($parts1, $parts2);
```

Writing this much code instead of two lines is against my religion.

2) The only reason to create this amount of code stricly not using `array_*` or `in_array` functions must be for some quiz or test, which I want to enter and win.

Comment: I guess in_array() is not allowed

Comment: @Dale ahh...please  use one more loop ...instead in_array() ...:P

Comment: @NullPointer I have my reasons for quitting :)

Answer (score 1):

Use array_intersect, array_diff and array_merge

```
$filter1 = "blueberries,abc,cornstarch,sugar";
$cval = strtoupper($filter1);         
$parts1 = explode(',',$cval);

$filter2 = "water,blueberries,sugar,cornstarch";
$values = strtoupper($filter2);
$parts2 = explode(',', $values);

print_r(array_intersect($parts1, $parts2));

print_r(array_merge(array_diff($parts1, $parts2), array_diff($parts2, $parts1)));
```

Array ( [0] => BLUEBERRIES [2] => CORNSTARCH [3] => SUGAR ) Array ( [0] => ABC [1] => WATER )

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the cartesian product of the two arrays.
If you find that `$parts1[$i] == $parts2[$j]`, it is correct to add `$parts1[$i]` to `$p`, but the opposite assumption (if they are different then add to `$q`) is wrong.
You should start with all elements in `$q` and when you have a match, add it to `$p` and remove it from `$q`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
    $array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
    $array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
    $result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

    print_r($result);
    ?>
```

This is the php library function.